# How to have independent clicks

Tags: java

I'm coding the ticktacktoe game, and i want to have every click have its own independent response. But my loops are messing with my output. its still under construction but i want to see results for me to progress

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class tictac extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton [][] game = new JButton[3][3];
    JLabel head = new JLabel("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    Font font = new Font("Time New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 20);
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,3,0,0);
    int row,column =0;
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();

    tictac(){
        super("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        //setLayout(flow);
        //add(head);

        setLayout(grid);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(1);
        setSize(500,500);

        for (row =0; row<3;row++ ){
            for(column =0; column <3;column++){
                game[row][column]= new JButton("");
                add(game[row][column]);
                game[row][column].addActionListener(this);
            }
        }
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


        Object source = e.getSource();
        int count=1;

        for (row =0; row<3;row++ ){
            for(column =0; column <3;column++){


                if ((source == game[row][column]) && (game[row][column].getText()=="") && (count==1) )
                    game[row][column].setText("X");

                        if (source == game[row][column] && (count % 2==0))
                        game[row][column].setText("O");
                        else if (source == game[row][column] && (count % 2==1))
                            game[row][column].setText("X");


                count++;
                }// end of first for

            } // end of second for

        }
    }







public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tictac two =  new tictac();
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi .. "But my loops are messing with my output." - how ?

Comment: Don't compare String objects using `==`.

Comment: i want the first click to give me an X, and then the next click to give an O, then the next click an X

Answer (score 1):

Some problems in your code:

- Like said in comments, don't compare using `==`. Use `equals` methods. 
  Like that:

```java
String str = "mytext";
if(str.equals("mytext")) // true !
```

- The method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` is called each time that an event occurs. It means that if you declare a variable inside its body, it will reinitialize the value when a new action occurs. Take a look at your variable `count`.
- Your variable `count` seems to related to the turn of player 1 and 2. The problem is that you are assigning a new value to this variable at each loop.

To solve your problem you should:

- Declare a variable outside of your `actionPerformed` method. A boolean is appropriate because you have only 2 player, and the value of a boolean is either true or false.
- Modify the value of your boolean when a player has done an action.
- According to the value of this boolean variable, you decide to put a `X` or a `O`

And finally some improvements:

- Take a look at the naming conventions when you are dealing with java language. For example, the first letter when you are declaring a class should be in uppercase. All these informations can be found there: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html
- Also, take a look at the different indent style: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style ; Personnaly i find K&R style suitable when programming in java
- In your game, handle the fact that you can't select a case that has already been choose before.
- In your game, closing the window does nothing. You should take a look at the javadoc of JFrame to use one of the predefined value as parameter. For example, you should be interested by doing this:

```java
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Very indepth answer. This is what I would've needed as a newcomer.
Maybe instead of a two dimensional array, a implementation of equals using a unique ID (hashcode, even?) would be the next step - a direction you could point towards.

Comment: I would say like the second answer for this point: casting the event of the source to JButton (as every JButton has a listener)

Answer (score 0):

If the desired behavior is as you stated in your comment:

> i want the first click to give me an X, and then the next click to
>   give an O, then the next click an X

... then your `actionPerformed()` code can be as simple as this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText(clickCount++ % 2 == 0 ? "X" : "O");
}
```

For that to work, of course also declare new class field:
`int clickCount = 0;`